# How to create alias addresses in Gmail without registering a new email address for each one?

Tags: gmail, alias

It appears I need to actually register new email address in Gmail, and then I can service them all from one Gmail login by adding them in Settings.

Is there a quicker/simpler way?

I do NOT mean using periods or plus signs. I mean actual **unique** and **different** email addresses `@gmail.com`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a [G Suite](https://gsuite.google.com/) account, you can [set up aliases](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33327?hl=en) to get received to the main email.

---

Other than using the `+`, `.` or `CAPS` within the email, there is no way to create an email alias for Gmail.

You *would* have to create a new email address and then connect it.